# Converting an SVG file, without using Imagemagick or Inkscape

Tags: software-recommendation, file-conversion, macos

I sometimes need to convert SVG files to a different format.  Thus far I tried [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).  I first tried to use Inkscape, but it failed to produce useable results (possibly because of the size and complexity of the graphics I was trying to convert).  Inkscape is thus a no go for me.  I then installed Imagemagick by [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  It did work but I just could not help cringing at the amount of useless bloat it would pull on.  Today's update though installed the n-th implementation of [Python](https://www.python.org/) -- I already have the native OS X version (Python 2.7.5) and [Anaconda Python](http://continuum.io/), which allows me to run Python 3 in its own self contained environment.  Call me OCD but getting a completely unrequested third instance of Python convinced me that Imagemagick had to go (and did, I removed it and all associated bloat).  Now unfortunately I am without means of converting SVG files.  I can, and will, do my best to avoid the damned things, but it would be helpful if anybody can suggest a *self contained* and *unbloated* alternative that I can use should the need arise.

Comment: Imagemagick requires you to install Python? It doesn't seem to for me, could you elaborate?

Comment: It did when I installed Imagemagick -- if this annoying behaviour has been rectified I would not know because I removed the lot and never reinstalled Imagemagick

Comment: I don't see any Python dependencies here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb Also I have it installed without additional Python